# Error message [null] or [null,null,null,null] when using browser.actions protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, cucumberjs

When runnning code like:

`element(by.css('input')).sendKeys(arg1).then(function() {
          browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform().then(callback);
    });`

Or anything using `browser.actions()`

I'm getting an error message like:

`1) Scenario: User goes back to search results - features\headerNavigations.feature:31
   Step: When I enter "1000W Rotary Lawnmower" - features\headerNavigations.feature:34
   Step Definition: ..\node_modules\cucumber-tsflow\src\BindingDecorator.ts:163
   Message:
     [ null ]`

Ever since updating to chromedriver 2.27 I'm seeing this issue.

- Node: 6.9.1
- Protractor: 5.1.0
- Chrome: 56.0
- Chromedriver: 2.27

Seen this which maybe similar:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4067

And raised a question here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/chromedriver-users

Not seeing much action from the protractor or chromedriver community

Comment: It's unclear what is it you're asking. Please amend your question.